# multiple definition of <function>

Tags: c, gcc

```
/tmp/ccTQFVCP.o: In function `whiteSpace':
/home/tommo/fly/flyc/config.c:12: multiple definition of `whiteSpace'
/tmp/cc0ccMfz.o:/home/tommo/fly/flyc/config.c:12: first defined here
/tmp/ccTQFVCP.o: In function `lineEnd':
/home/tommo/fly/flyc/config.c:16: multiple definition of `lineEnd'
/tmp/cc0ccMfz.o:/home/tommo/fly/flyc/config.c:16: first defined here
/tmp/ccTQFVCP.o: In function `makeSubStr':
/home/tommo/fly/flyc/config.c:20: multiple definition of `makeSubStr'
/tmp/cc0ccMfz.o:/home/tommo/fly/flyc/config.c:20: first defined here
```

I'm getting this for every function in my file config.c

Every one of my header files has a #ifndef FILE_H header block thing.

Why is it doing this?

```
TARGET   = fly
SRC      = main.c gfx.c transform.c entity.c list.c v3.c config.c airplane.c
CPPFLAGS = -Wall 
LDFLAGS  = -lglfw -lGL -lGLU
DEBUG    = -g

linux: 
    @echo Building for Linux...
    gcc $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEBUG) $(LDFLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(TARGET)
    @echo All done.
clean:
    rm $(TARGET)
help:
    @echo "Available targets for fly"
    @echo " linux: build for linux (default)"
    @echo " clean: clean up directory"

.PHONY: help clean
```

That's my Makefile. **git pull from https://github.com/tm1rbrt/fly If you wanna try to build yourself**

Comment: It looks like config.c and/or config.o is getting passed to the linker twice for some reason.  What commands are executed when you try to `make`?

Comment: tommo@ubuntu:~/fly/flyc$ make 
Building for Linux... 
gcc -Wall  -g -lglfw -lGL -lGLU main.c gfx.c transform.c entity.c list.c v3.c config.c airplane.c -o fly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this: [main.c includes config.c](https://github.com/tm1rbrt/fly/commit/a54be00391faaa607823cdef5e016303bbb2f4df#diff-5). As a consequence, you get everything in config.c twice. It's unconventional that C files include each other, so I recommend to drop the include.

Comment: Sorry Martin, i did remove the itoa's and atoi's when i tried to build on linux earlier, I didn't push the changes. I have done that now. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, I was wrong including the application.cpp file in the main.cpp, after changing it to application.hpp it fixed the issue.